# HTML CSS can't make image fit screen diagonally

Tags: html, css, image

I don't have much knowledge about html and css and I couldn't find the answer on the internet so I am here.

Problem:
I am trying to make an image fill top part of the screen but one thing stops me from it and it's the default margin of the `<body>`. I've managed it by using `margin: -10px;` But now the image can't fill the screen by `20px`, probably because there is no margin, image still thinks screen is that big.

[image: the current problem]

```css
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -10px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 1600px;
     
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 70%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top 10px;
}

.cont {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main-text {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="cont">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWZAk.jpg">
        <div class="main-text">Big Ass Title</div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

NOTE: If you have any questions or didn't understand anything about the question, please ask because I am ready for any answer. :) Thanks.

Comment: use background-image CSS property w cover.

Comment: Why `width: 1600px`  and not `100%`  to your image ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus when i use 100% its the same result. I did 1600px to make sure its larger that the screen didn't help tho

Comment: _"I've managed it by using margin: -10px;"_ Why not just set it to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is meant to be a decoration(design), then background is fine to use.

`.cont` can be a `flex` or `grid` element, to avoid position absolute and possible unwanted sides effects.

here an example with a background and grid:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh; /* optionnal if it does not have a purpose */
}
.cont {
  height: 300px; /* guessed from your code */
  display: grid; /* default make a single column*/
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/600/300) 0 0 / cover; /* background covering */
}
.main-text {
  margin-block: auto; /* vertical-centering in its row from here */
  margin-inline-start:70px;
  font-size: 100px; /* from your code */
  color: white; /* from your code */
  font-weight: normal; /* you looked for this? */
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000; /*Optionnal  increase readability*/
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
        <h1 class="main-text">Big Ass Title</h1><!-- if that's a title, then make it a title ;) -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Mannn. tysm how you be walking around with this much knowable lol

Answer (score 1):

Generally to eliminate all the margins and paddings you can add:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

By the way I attached a snippet where it's working as you requested. Is better to eliminate the margins than adding a negative margin, if you want to do it that way you must to compensate it in the width to achieve the 100% width intended.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-text {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="cont">
    <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/941/thumb-1920-941898.jpg">
    <div class="main-text">Big Ass Title</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```